# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: java, mysql, macos

I'm using Mysql on My MacBookPro osx 10.9.
when i type the command in the terminal

`Mihikas-MacBook-Pro:~ mihika$ mysql` mysql does indeed start.

But when i show databases:

```
mysql> show databases;

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)***
```

and i can't add any databases to this

```
mysql> create database db;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database '
```

i even tried this command:

```
Mihikas-MacBook-Pro:~ mihika$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Basically for any command i type it gives me "access denied".
i even tried creating new user..but i guess i need to be the root user.
when i was logging in as root ,it constantly denied my password whereas it's actually right.

I installed mysql using: `bash <(curl -Ls http://git.io/eUx7rg)`

i am new to Mac OSX
please give me a step by step guide on this.
and also tell em how to switch between users.

i even uninstalled and reinstalled mysql to try solving the problem.

thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

The script you used to install MySQL generated you a password, and you need to use that password to connect to the database.

From the script:

```
mypass="$(cat /dev/urandom | base64 | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9_ | head -c8)"
echo $mypass > ~/Desktop/MYSQL_PASSWORD
```

From the lines above, I'd guess that there's a password on your desktop named `MYSQL_PASSWORD`. You can use it to connect to the database using this command:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

When prompted, enter the password from the file on the desktop.

To be extra tricky, you could use this command to connect to the database:

```
mysql -uroot -p`cat ~/Desktop/MYSQL_PASSWORD`
```

Comment: yes indeed a file was provided with that name. but i'm still getting an "access denied"

Comment: will usig xammp help?i want to connect mysql to netbeans for java programming